# Shared custom NestJS modules gives "not a part of the currently processed module" error

Tags: typescript, nestjs

We are running a couple of NestJS apps for different services. They all share some common code, in our case a ConfigModule and a CacheModule. I want to break these out and put them in a corporate "common" npm package in order to minimize code copying.

I'm running into a error though:

> Nest cannot export a component/module that is not a part of the
> currently processed module (ConfigModule). Please verify whether each
> exported unit is available in this particular context

I'm a bit lost as to what the problem actually is. Any help is much appreciated.

In `app.ts` on service A:

```js
import { ConfigModule } from '@company/npm-common';
...
@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule, ...],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Right now `@company/npm-common` is imported in package.json with `file:../npm-common`

`npm-common/index.ts`:

```js
export *  from './Config';
```

`npm-common/Config/index.ts`

```js
export { ConfigService } from './config.service';
export { ConfigModule } from './config.module';
```

`npm-common/Config/config.service`:

```js
import { Global, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from './config.service';

@Global()
@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ConfigService,
      useValue: new ConfigService(),
    },
  ],
  exports: [ConfigService],
})
export class ConfigModule {}
```

Comment: it looks like the code above is your config.module. can you please also share the config.service file as well ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The stupid answer to this question was that the main application and the external modules loaded different versions of NestJS. Seems that version 5.5 is not compatible with version 6 in this sense.

Comment: Faced similar problem with ConfigHostModule that I don't use at all. How did you found the reason of the error?

Comment: I didn't. If I remember correctly I just noticed the difference in versions, change it so they both used the same, and then it worked. No idea why.

Comment: Wish I had seen this 5 days ago. Ran into the same issue, it was because the versions across the two applications/packages weren't aligned