# NestJS problems with shared modules

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, microservices, config

I am trying to create a shared logging module in NestJS that can be shared between multiple micro-services.

The logging module works when it is part of the micro-service but when I extract the code to its own NPM module it no longer works.

Below is a sample of my shared NPM module code:

```js
 // my-logger.module.ts


import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { LoggerModule } from 'nestjs-pino';

@Module({
  imports: [
    LoggerModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        pinoHttp: {
          level: process.env.LOG_LEVEL || 'info',
          redact: configService.get<string[]>('logger.redacted.fields'),
          prettyPrint: {
            colorize: false,
            singleLine: true,
            levelFirst: false,
            translateTime: "yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:MM:ss.l'Z'",
            messageFormat: '{req.headers.x-correlation-id} [{context}] {msg}',
            ignore: 'pid,hostname,context,req,res,responseTime',
            errorLikeObjectKeys: ['err', 'error'],
          },
        },
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class MyLoggerModule {}
```

Below is a sample of the App Module from my NestJS micro-service

```js
// app.module.ts

import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import configuration from '../config/configuration';
import { MyLoggerModule } from '@my-company/my-logger.module';
import { HttpModule } from '@nestjs/axios';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ load: [configuration] }),
    MyLoggerModule,
    HttpModule,
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

The micro-service builds and deploys correctly with the shared npm module. However, each time I send a new request it causes the service to restart with the following error:

```
node[1]: ../src/tcp_wrap.cc:149:static void node::TCPWrap::New(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&): Assertion `args[0]->IsInt32()' failed.
```

Does anyone have any ideas on why this is failing ?

Note: I am guessing it has something to do with the ConfigService/ConfigModule being used in both modules. However, I don't understand why the same code works when it is part of the micro-service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We experienced similar issues trying to configure shared modules and ran into a whole host of issues. The root cause was the package versions and that these were not aligned. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55690586/4081730) pointed me in the right direction.

In summary, double check all package version numbers across both applications and shared packages.